# alias pip to sudo pip

Tags: sudo, pip

When using `pip` I almost always use `sudo` because otherwise it lacks permissions. I plan on adding an `alias pip="sudo pip"` in my `.zshrc` file. Is there a reason I shouldn't do that?

The main issue I can think of is that inside virtualenv I might not want to use `sudo`. Also, it might be dangerous. Is there a better way to do this? A smart and safe way?

Comment: Why dont you aliase it to `spip` or something similar?

Comment: I ended up doing that, but im curious if there is a better way so i can always just use `pip`. Especially useful when copy-pasting install commands or running other people's install scripts

Comment: IMHO the smartest way to use sudo is to **type** sudo, so that you know when you're running with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is never use `pip` outside of a `virtualenv`, so there is never a need to `sudo pip`, ever. For you system installs of python packages the dependencies within the package manager should take care.

Use separate virtualenvs for each of your python utilities/programs. This allows you to run appropriate python versions and prevents you from 'bouncing' version if one program requires version X of a package and some other utility version Y of the same package.

Never using pip on the global python also prevents you from breaking the (system) python setup inadvertently.